# Android video starts playing one minute after buffering in done

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I used vitamio library for playing rtsp.
Although I'm having `videoView.start();` on my code, video starts playing one minute after buffering in done!

but if I change orientation after buffering is done, video starts to play immediately!
I have the following code and I know changing orientation calls this method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (videoView != null)
        videoView.setVideoLayout(VideoView.VIDEO_LAYOUT_SCALE, 0);
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

But I don't know what exactly makes the video start and I am unable to force it to start playing(immediately after buffering is done) in any other way than changing orientation. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced when a VideoView has a dimension of 0, the video won't play.
Make sure that you set the initial dimensions.

Furthermore, I would try setup the layout from the beginning:
`videoView.setVideoLayout(VideoView.VIDEO_LAYOUT_SCALE, 0);`

I would set the dimensions after receiving the oncVideoSizeChanged callback e.g.,

```
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams vLayout = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();
            vLayout.width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            vLayout.height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

            float aspectRatio = (float) width / height;
            float screenRatio = (float) vLayout.width / vLayout.height;
            float topMargin = 0, leftMargin = 0;

            if (screenRatio < aspectRatio)
                topMargin = (float) vLayout.height
                        - ((float) vLayout.width / aspectRatio);
            else if (screenRatio > aspectRatio)
                leftMargin = (float) vLayout.width - (vLayout.height * aspectRatio);

            vLayout.setMargins((int) leftMargin, (int) topMargin, 0, 0);
            mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(vLayout);
        }
```

Comment: Please tell me how to set the initial dimensions. Should that be done in XML or Java file? besides, setting up the layout from the beginning did not help.

Comment: Normally, I would set dimensions once we have received a onVideoSizeChanged callback. I have updated the answer, assuming the videoview is located inside a FrameLayout

Comment: Thank you for your code, but it did not solve the problem. I debugged my code and figured out that the video actually starts to play but stops again inside Looper.Class for buffering, and by decreasing the buffersize it could start faster than before. @florianpilz

Comment: How did you decrease the buffersize?

Comment: There is a method in io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView that takes care of buffer size: videoView.setBufferSize();

Comment: Hi @NimaK , exactly how much buffer size should be, i am using vitamio with rmtp streamings...

Comment: @KaranNagpal depends on your speed and how much you wanna buffer before getting the play started